# Can't Push To Heroku (Can't find Rake 10.3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

rails newbie here. I'm working through the tutorial on railstutorial.org on a Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine. It's been pretty smooth sailing up until I got to heroku. When I want to push my app to heroku, it complains that it could not find rake-10.3.2. I checked heroku, and the application seems to be empty. However, I have rake-10.3.2 in my application, and if use "bundle show rake", it shows the correct version.

```
brandon@brandon-virtualbox:~/rails_projects/first_app$ bundle show rake
/home/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.3.2
```

That looks okay, but when I try to push it to heroku, I get:

```
brandon@brandon-virtualbox:~/rails_projects/first_app$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 66, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Writing objects: 100% (66/66), 14.46 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 66 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:dry-springs-4465.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:dry-springs-4465.git'
```

I noticed that it's using version 2.0.0 (which I have installed), but it's attempting to install the dependencies using 1.6.3. I'm not sure if that is related to the issue or not. My Gemfile is here:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I've been messing with it for a while, and have had no luck. I'm using RVM as well, but I'm a total newbie so I'm not sure what kind of impact that would have. If anyone would know what's going on, I'd appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this now too...  RubyGems.org is flaky at times, I'm going to assume it's one of those times.

Comment: Yup, RubyGems is having issues: https://twitter.com/rubygems_status/status/489119131862462464

Comment: Hey thanks so much! It was really blowing my mind how difficult it was for me to push an app with almost nothing in it.

Comment: Yeah it happens on occasion...  It's working for me now, try it again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was caused because I had *some* gems, but not all of them, under version control in `vendor/cache`. It seems that when `vendor/cache` is present, Heroku will not go to any of the other sources.

I solved this problem by moving the gem that I needed cached to another location, and then removing the `vendor/cache` folder from version control.