# Cannot push to Heroku: "Could not find rake-11.1.2 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I'm having trouble pushing my project to `Heroku` it's telling me I'm missing a gem `rake 11.1.2` yet running `gem list rake` tells me I do have rake 11.1.2 installed. 
[image]

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: @JimVanFleet http://pastebin.com/PupEJ2n6

Comment: do you have anything in vendor/cache per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768672/cant-push-to-heroku-cant-find-rake-10-3-2

Comment: @JimVanFleet removing the vendor/cache folder fixed the problem for me, could you explain what this folder is for and why this caused any problems? You can add it in a dedicated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved by removing `vendor/cache` from the codebase before pushing to Heroku.  This potentially confusing result arises from the differences in behavior exhibited by `bundle` under different circumstances.

Using `bundle` at your workstation, the command will exhibit [this behavior](http://bundler.io/v1.11/bundle_install.html):

*While installing gems, Bundler will check vendor/cache and then your system's gems. If a gem isn't cached or installed, Bundler will try to install it from the sources you have declared in your Gemfile.*

This yields the results expected by the OP, a working setup.

The `bundle` command on Heroku, however, is preparing to run your application under web traffic load, an entirely different set of stresses from development.  On Heroku, the `bundle` command executes with the `--deployment` flag, which will exhibit [this behavior](http://bundler.io/v1.11/deploying.html):

*If you have run bundle pack, checked in the vendor/cache directory, and do not have any git gems, Bundler will not contact the internet while installing your bundle.*

Bundler is making the assumption here, based on the presence of the `vendor/cache` directory, that the `bundle pack` command has been run,and the gems are pre-provisioned.  Since `rake`, then, wasn't present in `vendor/cache` this was the resulting error.

OP may have resolved the issue by either removing the relevant gems from `vendor/cache` or by issuing the `bundle pack` command and checking the gems into source control.  The first is more common.